# Why Do all gods in hindusim who took incarnation on earth Are localised To indian subcontinent?

Tags: avatars

All gods Mentioned in hinduism, who took incarnation on earth are Localised near or inside Indian subcontinent, Why is this so?Is there any specific reason for it?Does it have something to do with human civilizations at that time?

Comment: What is your definition of God? *Brahman*, then no. By Taittiriya Upanishad, knower of brahman is himself a brahman. This implies there must be hundreds (if not thousands) of others across the globe too. We only know few and glorify them.